# Django Language Change Anchors vs. Options

Tags: django

I have a dropdown list of languages that looks something like the following:

```
<ul class="languages hoverSelectorBlock">
    {% get_current_language as current_lang %}
    {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'set_language' %}" lang-code="{{ lang.0 }}"
               class="change_language{% if current_lang == lang.0 %} current_language {% endif %}"
               {% if current_lang == lang.0 %}selected="selected"
               {% else %}selected=""{% endif %}>{{ lang.1 }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The documentation says that it needs to be submitted as a POST request.  From my understanding that means I need to change the anchor tags into options.  But I want the same behavior such that when you click a language it will submit the form and reload the current page in that language.

Will the set_language view work with anchor tags?  If I need to change them to a select with options, how can I submit the form when one of the options is clicked without the need for a submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `select options` and wrap them in a `form with an id`. You can submit the form [on the select element's change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change).

```
<form id="my_form">
    <select onchange="submit_my_form()">
    ...
    </select>
</form>


function submit_my_form(){
    document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
}
```

Comment: So use option tags for the languages and wrap all of them in the select?

Comment: Yes, then that select elements `onchange` will be triggered every time you change the selected option. If this answer helps you consider accepting it.